# install robolectric with maven and eclipse for android testing

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, robolectric

I passed more than four hours in the internet looking for a way/tutorial/guide to install Robolectric in Eclipse/Maven , but I didn't find anything concrete.

I tried by adding the dependency in the POM, it doesn't work.

I tried as well to install it locally (create a new java-project and link to the test folder) just to test it, but it was not working as well (because the application is a maven one).

Can someone help me?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it yesterday :)

Here's what I had to add into my pom.xml

**Some versions**

```
<fest-android.version>1.0.7</fest-android.version>
<robolectric.version>2.2</robolectric.version>
<junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
<android.test.version>4.2.2_r2</android.test.version>
```

**Some dependencies**

```
<!-- Test Dependencies  -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
  <artifactId>fest-android</artifactId>
  <version>${fest-android.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
    <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
    <version>${robolectric.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>android</groupId>
     <artifactId>android</artifactId>
     <version>${android.test.version}</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Obviously if you don't use fest-android, you don't need the version and dependency in your pom.

**Surefire in the *build* tag**

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
          <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

**Point to your tests folder**

By default, surefire looks for tests classes in /src/test/java , however if you changed that, configure the test folder just before the ending *build* tag as:

```
<testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
```

**Done !**

Cheers.

Comment: Inspired from https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample/blob/master/pom.xml. You can see that they use *com.google.android* instead of just *android* artifacts. I don't know about *com.google.android*, but for *android* you can download them with https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer .

Comment: +1 for your structured and detailed answer. I test this again tonight and give feedback. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You may wanna have a look at https://github.com/blurpy/kouchat-android/blob/robolectric-snapshot/kouchat-android-impl/pom.xml as well. They don't include the surefire plugin, so I guess it's called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with [m2e-android](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/) and will be fixed in the next release:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/52

Please follow [my Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/rgladwell) or subscribe to the [Maven Android Developers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/maven-android-developers) for updates.